# Golang JSON RawMessage literal

Tags: json, go

Is it possible to create a json.RawMessage literal in Golang?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
type ErrorMessage struct {
    Timestamp string
    Message   json.RawMessage
}

func getTestData() ErrorMessage {
    return ErrorMessage{
        Timestamp: "test-time",
        Message:   "{}"
    }
}
```

Or something like that. [This](http://play.golang.org/p/C1tXFi23Bw) is the most succinct I've seen. I have not been able to find an example of a "struct" literal for creating raw json messages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The underlying data type for [json.RawMessage](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) is a `[]byte`

You can convert your string, or use a byte slice directly in the literal

```
msg := ErrorMessage{
    Timestamp: "test-time",
    Message:   []byte("{}"),
}
```

Note that to actually marshal that as expected, you need to use `*json.RawMessage`, which you can't take the address of in a literal context.